# Determine the variable name of binary file id - POST request with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post, serialization, binary

This started as a simple question and now has become more of a personal challenge than a question. Here goes!

**Background**

I have a mobile application that collects user-specified data via standard tables and also collects a single photo that is stored as a binary file.  The app allows you to specify the location of a server-side script to handle the data that it collects - the script for the binary object is a different script than the one for the alphanumeric data (app requires them as separate, not me).  The documentation/support on the app is sparse (part of the reason this has become a personal challenge more than a question).  I am using PHP to handle the data and put it into a MySQL database.

**Simple Part: The alpha-numeric data**

There are some fields that are pre-defined in the application, such as lat/long.  I used serialize($_POST) to insert the results into a temp MySQL database to get the database-specific names so that my PHP code could put them into a MySQL database permanently.  For instance, latitude was submitted as ecLatitude - who would have guessed.  Once I knew it was ecLatitude I could handle it and put it how/where I wanted.  Of course fields I defined were no problem.

**Hard Part: The binary object**

So now my problem is the binary object (the photo).  As with some database fields, I do not have control over the name of the file.  Seems that standard practice is to call the file 'file', or if I was using an HTML interface I would call it whatever I wanted, because I could use $_FILES and look for the name I specify.  So it seems I need to somehow serialize the binary object to determine the id of the actual file, not the file name.  By that I mean that if the file was called picture.jpg and was submitted as photo, I need to know 'photo' not 'picture.jpg'.

**Where I'm at**

Every example I've seen starts with knowing the name of the binary object id (in this case 'photo'), as you would expect this to be a rather obvious variable.  I tried encoding the object prior to serializing it, but that still seemed to return the non-unique name (picture.jpg), not the id, in the MySQL database.

***edit - I tried the following code for the blob-specific script.

```
$outputfields= serialize(base64_encode($_POST));
$query="INSERT INTO varnames (data) values ('".$outputfields."')";
```

Is this possible inside PHP, or do I need to do network monitoring?

Sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology - I tried to couch that with my simplistic example terms.

Comment: Add some code.. Definitely no need to do network monitoring, but the **Where I'm at** section absolutely makes zero sense without code.

Comment: @Evert - fair enough - I added a small portion of the code just trying to capture the variable name.  (excuse the terminology, again) I know the name of the individual records of the blob - I do not know the variable name of the blob.

Comment: So basically your question comes down to wanting to know what type of file it was? There's no way you can figure out it was simply a 'photo', but the file extension (in $_FILES) may help.. does that not suffice?

Comment: P.S.: The small portion of code you added does not help, and is in fact terrible. There's security holes in it and it will be very easy for this to break. Look up PDO, escaping and parameter binding.

Comment: thanks for the quasi-constructive criticism - I'll dig around more.  I know it is a jpeg.  Likely my combination of inexperience with php (implementation and terminology) is clouding my ability to ask the proper question.

Comment: serialize(base64_encode($_POST));  <-- you most likely want to reverse those function calls to: base64_encode(serialize($_POST));